# How to fix problem when page is loaded, but not displayed?

Tags: cypress

I am writing test for website that runs locally on my computer (using docker). I want to put sign in information and sign in to website. When I run this test, it will put in sign in information, click to sign in button, everything seems to be fine, but next page will not load, test passed. I can see in report that (PAGE LOAD) --page loaded-- (NEW URL) etc., but new page not displayed.

```
return false
})

Cypress.config(
{
"baseUrl": "http://czechitas-is.localhost"
}
);

describe('Test prihlaseni do ISu', function() {
it('Prihlaseni k domene', function() {
cy.visit('/cs')
})

it('Kliknuti na tlacitko prihlaseni', function() {
cy.get('#frm-signIn-login')
.type('test')
.should('have.value', 'test')

cy.get('#frm-signIn-password')
  .type('test')
  .should('have.value', 'test')

  cy.contains('Přihlásit').click()

  cy.url().should('include', '/cs/account/sign/in')
})
})
```

Comment: I guess you'll always see the same page after logging in? Just get an element which is not available on the login page and end your test (after the `url()`) with a check for that element.

Comment: @Mr.J. I try that, but without efect. I am still on login page. Cypress just told me, that he can´t find element. When I manually put there login information, it will log me.

Comment: Have you tried running the test headful? Via the testrunner you can go trough your test and even use the browser developer tools. Maybe that has a suggestion why the page wouldn't load.

Comment: Yeah, all my test I run trough testrunner. Because of it I know, that test has sign in me and get new URL.